# How to redirect to previous page in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am using Aurelia for my project,Now I have problem in navigating to previous page.I want to know are there any ways to get that previous router information from Aurelia router object.

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('test', {});
```

I read some github issue related to this, but I couldn't find solution.
furthermore are there any way to got that previous router state from below mention code.This code I got from github

```
router.currentInstruction
```

Comment: the router have a [`navigateBack` function.](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/router/class/Router/method/navigateBack/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding my comment as an answer so you can vote it and close.

you can use the [`navigateBack`](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/router/class/Router/method/navigateBack/) function from the router instance..